# Graph as an alternative to PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

Currently we are forced to use PowerShell to access many of the Exchange properties that are not available via the Graph API. Graph would be preferable for us primarily because it scales much better. Are there plans to make these Exchange properties available via Graph? If so, what is the roadmap for this? Examples of these properties are:

1. Users:

   1. ExchangeGuid
   2. ArchiveGuid
   3. ArchiveState
   4. LegacyExchangeDN
   5. DeliverToMailboxAndForward
   6. ForwardingAddress
   7. ForwardingSmtpAddress
   8. HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled
   9. Languages
   10. RecipientType
   11. RecipientTypeDetails
   12. ResourceCapacity
   13. ServerName
2. Groups:

   1. HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled
   2. LegacyExchangeDN
   3. RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Powershell is the way to move forward. If this is a feature request then please post it in O365 Uservoice. Here's the related thread talks about the same - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/397a70ba-99c1-4cf4-8ddd-6062a7911447/how-to-get-exchange-online-properties-of-office-365-user-by-using-azure-ad-graph-api-?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 0):

RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled is already exposed via Graph APIs and maps to allowExternalSenders property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-beta

Currently, HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled is not exposed via MS Graph. The O365 Groups team is already tracking them in our partner request backlog. However, we don't have an estimated ETA yet on when this feature would be ready.

Why do you need the ExchangeLegacyDN property exposed? Can you explain your scenario when this is needed?